# CakePHP - read file from outside webroot

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I have a model in /app/Model/User.php where I would like to read a file.
The file is located in /app/View/Emails/html/welcome.html:

```
$message = file_get_contents('../View/Emails/html/welcome.html');
```

This works locally but not online. What to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it wrong, what you try is already covered by the framework. See this, "[Sending templated emails](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails)". Reading the book is always a good idea. Copy and paste from the book:

> Emails are often much more than just a simple text message. In order
>   to facilitate that, CakePHP provides a way to send emails using
>   CakePHP’s view layer.
>
> The templates for emails reside in a special folder in your
>   applications View directory called Emails. Email views can also use
>   layouts, and elements just like normal views:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->template('welcome', 'fancy')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->to('bob@example.com')
    ->from('app@domain.com')
    ->send();
```

> The above would use app/View/Emails/html/welcome.ctp for the view, and
>   app/View/Layouts/Emails/html/fancy.ctp for the layout. You can send
>   multipart templated email messages as well:

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I modified my method so a template is used now. Thanks.